# How to stop git auto-update when switching branches?

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have two branches:

```
----master
  |
  |----lf
```

I developed some new feature in branch `lf` and get some output. Then, I tried to switch back to `master` (through `git checkout`) and execute the program to compare the result. Unfortunately, `git checkout master` will update what I did in `lf`:

```
M   Makefile
M   src/mainloop.c
M   src/threadpool.c
M   src/threadpool.h
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
```

As a result, I get the exact same project in two branches. This is not what I want. I don't want master auto update what I changed in `lf`.

My question are:

1. How to recover the code in `master` before I do branch (`git branch lf`)?
2. How to switch between different branches with no auto-update?

Comment: doing a git checkout does not do merges. Are you sure you didn't merge? You should be able to view history of master and roll it back

Comment: I am pretty sure the only thing I did is switch from `lf` to `master` through   git checkout master, then it auto update the new code in `lf`

Comment: @Steven what you describe definitely sounds like a normal behavior; see my answer for more details.

Comment: Related: [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. How to recover the code in master before I do branch (`git branch lf`)?

Do a commit (e.g. `git commit -a -m "…"`) **before doing `git checkout master`**.

Otherwise, do [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) if you don't want to do a "temporary" commit. Later on, do `git checkout lf && git stash pop` to retrieve your uncommitted code.

> 2. How to switch different branch with no auto up to date ?

Basically there is no "auto-update": the cause of what you observe is just that your working directory is not clean (i.e., there are some uncommitted modifications), and changing branch doesn't auto-update anything, it just keeps these modifications as is (otherwise that would lead to data loss!)

Also, a handy command that you may want to run anytime to get more insight on the current state of your [current-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary/#def_HEAD)/[index](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary/#def_index)/[working-directory](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary/#def_working_tree) is: [`git status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status).